# Postgres database network sharing does not work

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up a postgres server on Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. My server machine ip is 192.168.1.3 and i am trying to hit the server from Client machine 192.168.1.4 I always get connection time out and is the server up and running but i did changes to the postgres configuration files but in Vain.Please help me

I did the following steps:

Changed my Postgresql.config like the below

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
```

And pg_hba.config file as

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host     all             all             192.168.1.5/32          trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host     all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host     all             all             192.168.1.4/32          trust
```

Comment: Did you check windows firewall settings?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't somehow connecting via ipv6? Are you connecting via IP or name?

Comment: i m connecting via IP